How would Derrida have a deconstructive reading of norm over exception?
I am mostly familiar with Derrida's deconstructive reading of speech over writing in Of Grammatology. How about another binary opposition norm over exception? How would Derrida deconstruct norm over exception? Or which of his books offer insights into the deconstructive reading of norm over exception?
Thanks very much.

In limited Inc Derrida’s iterability (a word, sign, or rule gains meaning through repeatable use) touches on the stability of norms. Iterability implies that no rule or norm is ever “pure”; it must be able to be repeated and applied across different contexts. This repetition, however, opens up the possibility of exception where each instance of applying a norm is slightly different and brings with it the potential for deviation, thus suggesting every norm always carries within it the possibility of its own exception and challenging binary hierarchy that places the norm above the exception...

Thanks very much for sharing this. Very helpful. Thanks again.
